# How do I retrieve variables in a PowerShell script running as part of a VSTS build/release?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I am getting an error in VSTS when I run a powershell script.

I have powershell install on my agent. But I still get this error:

> The term 'Get-VstsInput' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program.

I am I missing something.

Comment: Are you writing a custom task, or are you just running a PowerShell script?

Comment: Sorry Should have mentioned powershell script.

Answer (score 6):

You can access variables in a PowerShell script with `$env:VariableName`. The only exception is secret variables. Those have to be explicitly passed into the script via a `param` block.

For example, if you had a variable named `$(Foo)`, you could access it in a PowerShell script as `$env:Foo`. If there are periods in the variable name, they are replaced with underscores. So `$(Foo.Bar)` becomes `$env:Foo_Bar`.

This also does not apply to PowerShell on Target Machines. If you run a PowerShell script on a remote machine via that task, you have to pass any variables as arguments, as the build agent's environment variables are not populated on the target machine(s).

There is no need to use the VSTS SDK unless you are writing a custom task.

Comment: I am trying to get release tag and all commits after release tag. How can I pass the release tag as variable ? since this changes after every prod release.

Comment: @gopal That's a totally different question. You wouldn't be able to get the tags with the `Get-VstsInput` cmdlet, either.

Comment: @gopal I don't know how you calculate your tag but you can fetch the Build Number reading the system variable [Build.BuildNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts) when in a build process or the Release name reading the  [Release.ReleaseName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch) variable when in a release process.

Comment: If you want to access `$(System.AccessToken)` you need to not only replace dots with underscores but also capitalize the name: `$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN`.

Comment: @Monsignor Powershell is case insensitive. You do not need to worry about capitalization.

Comment: @DanielMann On Windows yes, when running on an Ubuntu agent it seems to be case sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

`Get-VstsInput` is used for developing build/release tasks (not used for executing script in PowerShell task). More details, you can refer [VSTS DevOps Task SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib#vsts-devops-task-sdk) and [vsts-task-lib commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib/blob/master/powershell/Docs/Commands.md#get-vstsinput).

- If you want to use a defined variable in PowerShell task, you can use it with the format `$(variableName)`.
- If you want to get all the accessible variables for the build/release by PowerShell task, you can use the command `ls env:`.

Answer (score 0):

The method `Get-VstsInput` is part of "VSTS Task SDK for PowerShell", probably in the agent the SDK is not installed.

Install the SDK on the build server with this command:

`Save-Module -Name VstsTaskSdk -Path .\`

Comment: Thank you. I tried this in Powershell on the agent but I get this.

Save-Module -Name VstsTaskSdk -Path .\          
PS /Users/xxxx> Save-Module -Name VstsTaskSdk -Path .\             PS /Users/xxxx> Get-VstsInput                                         Get-VstsInput : The term 'Get-VstsInput' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.                                 Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
+ Get-VstsInput
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~